# How to controll input value with javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm practicing javascript but get strange behaviour i use if condition set input value less then equal to 10 but input value goes to 11 why it goes to 11 why if condition not false i want it stop to 10

Html Code :

```
<label for="quantity">QUANTITY</label>
<span class="quantity">
<input  type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity" value="1">

<button type="button" class="button-up"><i class="fas fa-chevron-up"></i></button>

<button type="button" class="button-down"><i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></button>
</span>
```

Css Code:

```
span {
                display: inline-block;
                position: relative;
}
            input {
                width: 6rem;
                text-align: center;
                padding: 1rem 0;
                border: none;
                font-size: 1.8rem;
                font-weight: 400;
                margin-left: 1rem;
                margin-right: 1rem;
                box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
            }
            .button-up {
                position: absolute;
                display: inline-block;
                background: #fff;
                border: none;
                padding: .1rem .4rem;
                font-size: 1.2rem;
                box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
            }
            .button-down {
                position: absolute;
                top: 2.8rem;
                display: inline-block;
                background: #fff;
                border: none;
                padding: .1rem .4rem;
                font-size: 1.2rem;
                box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
            }
```

Js code:

```
let quantity = document.querySelector('.quantity input')
let buttonUp = document.querySelector('.button-up');
let buttonDown = document.querySelector('.button-down')
buttonUp.addEventListener('click', () => {

    if(quantity.value <= 10) {

    quantity.value++;
    console.log(quantity.value)
    }
})
```

Comment: You can fix this by replacing `<=` to `<` inside if statement.

Comment: I know that but i want to know why if condition not false

Comment: It is false, but understand your code first.. when `quantity.value` = 10, then `quantity.value <= 10` is true.. then you are doing `quantity.value++` which makes `quantity.value` = 11.. so `console.log(quantity.value)` shows 11.. then on next click `quantity.value <= 10` is false, and click stops here.

Comment: @palaѕн why you don't post it as answer while it is the correct answer